# Convert jQuery dropdown change event handler into pure JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

To achieve better performance for our Shopify store, we disabled jQuery. Could you please help change jQuery code below to its JavaScript equivalent?

```
   <p class="cart-attribute__field">
      <label>How did you hear about us?</label><br>
      <select required class="required" id="how-did-you-find-us" name="attributes[How did you hear about us?]">
        <option value="Search (Google)"{% if cart.attributes["How Did You Find Us?"] == "Search (Google)" %} selected{% endif %}>Search (Google)</option>
        <option value="Event"{% if cart.attributes["How Did You Find Us?"] == "Event" %} selected{% endif %}>Event</option>
        <option value="Friend / Co-worker"{% if cart.attributes["How Did You Find Us?"] == "Friend / Co-worker" %} selected{% endif %}>Friend / Co-worker</option>
        <option value="Current Customer"{% if cart.attributes["How Did You Find Us?"] == "Current Customer" %} selected{% endif %}>Current Customer</option>
        <option value="Social Media"{% if cart.attributes["How Did You Find Us?"] == "Social Media" %} selected{% endif %}>Social Media</option>
        <option value="Ad"{% if cart.attributes["How Did You Find Us?"] == "Ad" %} selected{% endif %}>Ad</option>
        <option value="News"{% if cart.attributes["How Did You Find Us?"] == "News" %} selected{% endif %}>News</option>
        <option value="Other"{% if cart.attributes["How Did You Find Us?"] == "Other" %} selected{% endif %}>Other</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p class="cart-attribute__field find-other" style="display: none;">
      <label for="how-did-you-find-us-other">Other: </label>
      <input required class="required" id="how-did-you-find-us-other" type="text" name="attributes[How did you hear about us? - Other]" value="{{ cart.attributes["How Did You Find Us - Other"] }}">
    </p>
    
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
      $('#how-did-you-find-us').change(function() {
        if ($('#how-did-you-find-us').val() == 'Other') {
          $('.find-other').show();
        } else {
          $('.find-other').hide();
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event listeners are added using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and instead of `show`/`hide`, the `display` property of the element is used.

Also, read about [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
// Event listener that fires when the DOM is loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Get the elements
  let howDidYouFindUs = document.querySelector("#how-did-you-find-us")
  let findOther = document.querySelector(".find-other")
  
  // Change event listener
  howDidYouFindUs.addEventListener("change", function(){
    // Ternary operator to toggle the display
    findOther.style.display = howDidYouFindUs.value === "Other" ? "block" : "none"
  })
})
```

Working snippet:

```js
// Event listener that fires when the DOM is loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Get the elements
  let howDidYouFindUs = document.querySelector("#how-did-you-find-us")
  let findOther = document.querySelector(".find-other")
  
  // Change event listener
  howDidYouFindUs.addEventListener("change", function(){
    // Ternary operator to toggle the display
    findOther.style.display = howDidYouFindUs.value === "Other" ? "block" : "none"
  })
})
```

```html
<p class="cart-attribute__field">
  <label>How did you hear about us?</label><br>
  <select required class="required" id="how-did-you-find-us" name="attributes[How did you hear about us?]">
    <option value="Search (Google)">Search (Google)</option>
    <option value="Event">Event</option>
    <option value="Friend / Co-worker">Friend / Co-worker</option>
    <option value="Current Customer">Current Customer</option>
    <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
    <option value="Ad">Ad</option>
    <option value="News">News</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p class="cart-attribute__field find-other" style="display: none;">
  <label for="how-did-you-find-us-other">Other: </label>
  <input required class="required" id="how-did-you-find-us-other" type="text" name="attributes[How did you hear about us? - Other]" value="{{ cart.attributes[" How Did You Find Us - Other "] }}">
</p>
```

Comment: Louys, the text box doesn't display on choosing other. Could you please check the code?

Comment: Must be due to something else... I added a working snippet.

Comment: What is that templating code `{% ... %}` ?

Comment: This templating code is Shopify liquid code.

Comment: Is there more than one `.find-other` in the same page?

Comment: No. This is the page I'm working on, https://wanb9ote10omvtor-458195004.shopifypreview.com. . Please have a look.

Comment: If the link above doesn't work, please check https://packed-with-purpose.myshopify.com/?preview_theme_id=122332414012

Comment: Louys, could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active element? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked

Comment: It seems like there are a couple answers already. And at least 2 are pretty good. If none fits... Maybe the question needs to be improved. -- But thanks for that request to check on it. Makes me feel like a supertar ;)